# Create column named "Id" based on row index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column for my dataframe named "Id" where the value  is the row index +1.
I would like to be like the example below:

```
   ID  Col1  ...
0  1   a     ...
1  2   b     ...
2  3   c     ...
```

Answer (score 32):

You can add one to the index and assign it to the `id` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": list("abc")})

df["id"] = df.index + 1

df
#Col1   id
#0  a    1
#1  b    2
#2  c    3
```

Comment: It worked but when exporting to csv Col1 and ID are adding their values. (When col1 has 0 it adds)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Exporting to csv normally should not change the data frame.

Comment: Col1's values are 0 or 1. If for first row I have col1 value =0 and Id = 1, I get only 1 not 0,1 (on csv)

Comment: I tested on this data frame `df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [0, 1, 0]})` and it works fine. You might have some other column names and data format issue. For instance do you have comma in your number? Are they strings or floats etc..

Comment: Yeah I've messed up with some columns values, it's all fixed ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I converted the prediction list to an array then created an dataframe with group totals and plotted the dataframe

```
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)

#print(y_pred)
setosa=np.array([y_pred[i][0] for i in range(len(y_pred))])
versicolor=np.array([y_pred[i][1] for i in range(len(y_pred))])
virginica=np.array([y_pred[i][2] for i in range(len(y_pred))])

df2=pd.DataFrame({'setosa': [len(setosa[setosa>.5])],'versicolor': 
[len(versicolor[versicolor>.5])], 'virginica': [len(virginica[virginica>.5])] })
df2['id']=np.arange(0,1)
df2=df2.set_index('id')
df2.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['id'] = np.arange(0, len(df))
```